# join table with includes creating problem

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, left-join, rails-activerecord

Models structure:-

```
User has_many :subscriptions 
Blog  has_one :coupon
Subscription has_one :coupon
```

I am including the tables

```
User.includes(subscriptions: :coupon, :blogs)
```

I am trying to get all users data and only get the valid subscriptions corresponding to it.

If i do

```
User.includes(subscriptions: :coupon, :blogs).where(:state => 1).references(:subscriptions)
```

then i am getting the users having only valid subscriptions

So how to get all the users with preloaded blogs coupons and included with valid subscriptions???

Comment: rails version? This is becoming an important part of any rails question since v 5 implemented `left_joins` along with a few other new and different changes

Comment: What is `:blogs` in `User.includes(subscriptions: :coupon, :blogs)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to load all users, including those who don't have any valid subscriptions, but for each user be able to access only valid subscriptions, you need to define another association `valid_subscriptions`. It can be done this way:

In `user.rb`

`has_many :valid_subscriptions, -> { valid }, class_name: 'Subscription'`

In `subscription.rb`, define what being valid means.

`scope :valid, -> { where(state: 1) }`

Then you query can be `User.includes(:blogs, valid_subscriptions: :coupon)`

Comment: I want all users data and with that only valid subscriptions.. You interpreted the question wrong